# How can I integrate Magento products in my WordPress website?

Tags: wordpress, magento, e-commerce, integration

Is there a way to integrate Magento products from my Magento store in my WordPress website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is. The Magento plugin for WordPress enables you to show/advertise any Magento products anywhere on your WordPress website, as a widget or a line of shortcode. It's also fully customizable, easy to install without having to do any kind of programming and it's entirely free of use.

[Here's the link](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/magento/) to the plugin:

Hope that helps!

Comment: This plugin is no longer supported. If someone is looking for a new up-to-date plugin, there is Mag Products Integration for WordPress : https://wordpress.org/plugins/mag-products-integration/